# Remine installation on Fedora 27

Tags: rake, nokogiri, redmine, fedora-27

Greats everybody,

I have a problem with the gem nokogiri when i ask rake to generate secret token for redmine...
Here is the console dialog :

> [root@macbeth redmine]# /usr/local/bin/rake generate secret token
>
> [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Illformed requirement ["1.8.2 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32"]. Bundler cannot continue.
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                #  from /var/www/redmine/Gemfile:116
>    #  -------------------------------------------
>    #
>    gem 'nokogiri', '1.8.2 ruby java x64-mingw32 x86-mingw32'
>    #  -------------------------------------------

Any help welcome !

Thanks, Regards,
Franck

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry for inconvenience my informations were out of date...
Better results with redmine-3.4.4.zip file and this procedure actualised :
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall